# why is load address of kernel, ramdisk important in booting?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot

I am dealing with android boot.img which is a combination of compressed kernel, ramdisk, and dtb. I see from the serial console log from uboot about the booting process and here's the part that triggers my curiosity

```
CPU:   Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.2 at 792 MHz
CPU:   Temperature 27 C
Reset cause: POR
Board: MX6-SabreSD
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  1 GiB
PMIC:  PFUZE100 ID=0x10
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0, FSL_SDHC: 1, FSL_SDHC: 2
No panel detected: default to Hannstar-XGA
Display: Hannstar-XGA (1024x768)
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
check_and_clean: reg 0, flag_set 0
Fastboot: Normal
flash target is MMC:1
Net:   FEC [PRIME]
Normal Boot
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  3  2  1  0 
boota mmc1 
kernel   @ 14008000 (7272352)
ramdisk  @ 15000000 (869937)
fdt      @ 14f00000 (44072)
## Booting Android Image at 0x12000000 ...
Kernel load addr 0x14008000 size 7102 KiB
Kernel command line: console=ttymxc0,115200 init=/init video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1920x1080M@60,bpp=32 video=mxcfb1:off video=mxcfb:off video=mxcfb3:off vmalloc=256M androidboot.console=ttymxc0 consolebalank=0 androidboot.hardware=freescale cma=384M
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 14f00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x14f00000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Using Device Tree in place at 14f00000, end 14f0dc27
switch to ldo_bypass mode!

Starting kernel ...
```

The kernel's address is 14008000, ramdisk 15000000, fdt 14f00000.
I have found out that these values are saved in the boot.img header and when I manually mess with this values, the image will not boot even though the actual contents are not modified.

Why is this address so critical? Why does it have to be these values? why not other values?

One of my own guess is: 
these load address values are hardcoded inside the kernel so if I change it in the boot.img header it will cause side-effects. To elaborate my own theory, loading the kernel to the 'modified' load addr won't be a problem. But when actually executing the lines, it will cause severe problems because these codes are fixed to work with the proper 'load addr'.

Is my theory wrong? If so, I'd be grateful if you could correct me.

Comment: The kernel image is a non-relocatable binary. During the link phase of building the kernel, all relocatable, non-relative addresses are converted into absolute addresses using a specified load address as the base. For Linux ARM kernels, the convention is that this load address is 0x8000 from the start of physical memory.

Comment: That should be the answer, except one thing - the addresses converted to absolute using link address which is 0xc0008000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the U-boot finished, it needs to handover the further execution to kernel so that kernel takes care for all further processes. Plus Kernel have some set of routines which are essential to initialize the board.

These set of routines have a entry point [start_kernel()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L497). Before this some other routines are also called to execute `start_kernel`. That can be identified by this [linker script](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/bootp/bootp.lds) and this [init.S](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/bootp/init.S).

To maintain execution in this procedure kernel need to be started from a particular address, moreover its data segments and other memories are also attached with that so to load and run all these in a proper manner, exact memory location need to be provided.

With this kernel needs the device tree blob for probing the devices attached to it and the rootfs to bring up the user space, here to load the device tree and rootfs exact offsets are needed so that any data should not be missed or corrupted. Every single byte is important for all these execution.

So to safely bootup all these values are being stored in bootloader's configuration.